# How can I check in PHP if a $_POST is "empty" or zero?

Tags: php, post

I've got a for that (among other things) has an input field:

```
<input type="text" id="NumAthletes_Ratings" name="NumAthletes_Ratings" />
```

In my PHP code, I'd like to check if the user has entered no value or a 0. However, this code

```
    if (isset($_POST['NumAthletes_Ratings'])) {
        if ($_POST['NumAthletes_Ratings'] > 0) {
            echo 'POST Parameter is set to ' . $_POST['NumAthletes_Ratings'];
        } else {
            echo 'POST Parameter is set to Zero';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'POST Parameter is not set';
    }
```

prints `POST Parameter is set to Zero` regardless of an empty value or 0 being passed. How can I differentiate between those cases?

Comment: how about absolute comparison `===`

Comment: Have you tried `if(is_numeric($_POST['NumAthletes_Ratings']))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check for the string `"0"` (all `$_POST` variables are strings or arrays of strings):

```
if ($_POST['NumAthletes_Ratings'] > 0) {
        echo 'POST Parameter is set to ' . $_POST['NumAthletes_Ratings'];
    } elseif ($_POST['NumAthletes_Ratings'] === '0') {
        echo 'POST Parameter is set to 0';
    } else {
        echo 'POST Parameter is empty';
    }
```

Comment: "Almost" too simple ;-) Thanks for the obvious answer, solved my issue.